# Joint Trajectory Controller with velocity command interface reports success to early

Tags: joint-trajectory-controller, ros2-controllers

I want to control a manipulator with the Joint Trajectory Controller (JTC) by using the velocity command interface. I am using ros2_control respectively ros2_controllers on the master branch and I have a setup where I use a **velocity command interface** together with a **position and velocity state interface** for real hardware.

I am planning a trajectory with MoveIt MotionPlanning of RViz. After hitting `Plan & Execute` the JTC reports *"Goal reached, success!"* always far to early although there is still a big **position error** (e.g. the joint is only making 70% of the way). And when the JTC reports *"Goal reached, success!"* the line `traj_msg_external_point_ptr_.initRT(set_hold_position());` makes the JTC try to hold the wrong position if I understand it correctly.

It seems to me that the **sampling of the trajectory is not working properly** or rather I have a setup that makes it operate incorrectly. I tried to debug this a little and found that the trajectory, that MoveIt generates, looks okay, at least the desired positions look fine.
I tried to tweak the **gains for the JTC** in a lot of combinations but it mostly gets worse.

Any idea what could cause such a behavior or what parameter I should tune?

**EDIT:**
I used PlotJuggler to capture the data of the controller_state to better visualize the problem:

[image: Data of controller_state topic]

These are my settings for the JTC:

```
joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint_1
    command_interfaces:
      - velocity
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    state_publish_rate: 50.0 # Defaults to 50
    action_monitor_rate: 20.0 # Defaults to 20

    gains:
      joint_1:
        p: 0.5
        i: 0.0
        d: 0.0
        i_clamp: 0.0
        ff_velocity_scale: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem thanks to introspecting the `~/controller_state` topic with PlotJuggler.

The problem was with the **joint limits**. Lowering the `max_velocity` and the `max_acceleration` in the `joint_limits.yaml` fixed the problem for me. I think the joint limits within my hardware made it impossible to follow the trajectory. Planing a much slower trajectory on the other hand fixed that.

Comment: great that you fixed it. just to understand what the JTC is doing: how long is the trajectory you wanted to follow? did it end already at t=17s? because you did not set any constraints, which means there is only `stopped_velocity_tolerance=0.01`, which is always true with you trajectory and JTC stops "immediately" with success.

Comment: And please mark your question as solved by this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set any parameters from the [constraints](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/doc/parameters.html) structure?

Try to introspect the `~/controller_state` topic, e.g., with foxglove or plotjuggler. What is the position error and velocity feedback?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I edited my question and added the information you requested to give a better understanding of my problem.